# Routing in jHipster with Angular 4

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, angular-ui-router, jhipster

I just started a new Project in Angular 4 with the help of JHipster.

Out of the Box, Jhipster is using the `HashLocationStrategy`, so my URLs look like so: 
`localhost:8080/#/url`

Now for my project, I would like to use Html5-pushstate, with an added prefix like so:
`localhost:8080/myproject/url`

For that end, I made the following changes:

---

**application.yml**

Here I simply added the line 'context-path: /myproject'

```
server:
    session:
        cookie:
            http-only: true
 -> context-path: /myproject
```

---

***.module.ts**

In every .module.ts file that contained something like
`RouterModule.forRoot(accountState, { useHash: true })`, I removed the `{useHash: true}`-part.

Note: Every RouterModule in the jHipster-Project uses .forRoot by default.

---

This already had a huge effect, since I can now open my page via `localhost:8080/myproject/` and navigate it from within the page.

To successfully open the page from a bookmarked link like `localhost:8080/myproject/url`, I've created the following Java-File, following the idea of this [guide](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/010_tip_configuring_html_5_mode.html) that was initially meant for AngularJS

---

**Routes.java**

```
package my.company.mc.config;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Routes {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^.]*}")

    public String redirect(){
        return "forward:/";
    }

}
```

---

From here on out, most everything seemed to work fine, until I noticed today, that I can't directly acces a page with an URL like `localhost:8080/myproject/entity/{id}`

Whenever I try to directly access it, I get a 404 fromy my Spring Webserver.

I suspect it has something to do with my Routes.Java file, and it not actually correctly routing every direct page-access via the index.html.

I've tried a couple of things, but always fell short of actually solving my problem, and since I'm still pretty fresh when it comes to Angular 4 and Spring, I'm starting to get tired of googling for a possible Solution, that finally doesn't work since there's too many differences from the project from the get go.

I hope someone here can help me, and If you're missing any information, please tell me so, I'll happily comply.

---

**1. Edit:**

I implemented the Filter-Class as shown in Gaël's [Link](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4794#issuecomment-304097246) and added it into my SecurityConfigurations.java, like so:

---

**SecurityConfigurations.java**

```
(...)
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint())
 ->  .and()
 ->    .addFilterBefore(new AngularRouteFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
 ->    .exceptionHandling()
 ->    .authenticationEntryPoint(http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint())
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
        .key(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getRememberMe().getKey())
(...)
```

Additionally, I removed the Context-Path for now, since I first wanted to implement a 'vanilla'-version before making any alterations.

Sadly I couldn't make it work. I tried placing the Filter in different places of the Filter Chain. I also tried removing my Routes.java, since I wasn't sure on how exactly it interacted with the new Filter.

In the End, I think it may just be my lack of understanding on how the Angular-Routing interacts with the Spring-Backend and vice-versa, that prevents me from finding a proper solution.

Comment: Try to adapt the filter class in my comment https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4794#issuecomment-304097246 It was not made for a context path but you can adapt it, still there are probably more cases to test.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I tried implementing this solution but couldn't make it work. I edited my post to reflect my expirience. It seems like changing things in the Backend may not be enough. Or  my inexpirience may just hold me back. :/

Comment: It's been a long time since I tried it, I might have regsitered the filter in WebConfigurer.java? Have you checked that your filter is called under debugger?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou
Tried registering the Filter in WebConfigurer but that only led to the index of the site not loading anymore at all, I might've done it wrong though?!


`@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean angularRouteFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        Filter angularRouterFilter = new AngularRouteFilter();
        beanFactory.autowireBean(angularRouterFilter);
        registrationBean.setFilter(angularRouterFilter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }`

Comment: The Filter got called even without it being registered in WebConfigurer. So I don't think that was the problem.

Thank you btw for your quick help, it's nice to see the JHipster-Team so active on StackOverflow!